# getArgument() is always null

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I know this question has been asked over and over again, but I can't make this work.

I just want to pass a parameter from an Activity to a Fragment. I have tried everything I could find online but I can't make it work. I always get the NullPointerException error. I have even tried a test code with the same result. So here it is:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("my_key", "My String");
        MyFragment myFrag = new MyFragment();
        myFrag.setArguments(bundle);
    }
}
```

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.game);
        String getArgument = getArguments().getString("my_key");
        text.setText(getArgument);
        return view;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.test.test.MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_game"
    class="com.example.test.test.MyFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragmentlayout" />

</FrameLayout>
```

fragmentlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_game"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#411124"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.test.test, PID: 11917
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test.test/com.example.test.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.test.test.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:20)
                                                                         at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2353)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:959)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1149)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1251)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2311)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5901)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
                                                                         at com.example.test.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

How can I get the parameter without the error?

Comment: TextView tag need to be close in fragmentlayout.xml

Comment: @lelloman I saw an answer from you but I saw you deleted it. Any particular reason?

Comment: The solution to your problem (which I gave you in the answer) is trivial and there are many examples and resources on the internet that you can read. Since you didn't seem interested there is no reason to have that answer online

Comment: @lelloman I was and I am still interested. I was not in front of the PC to try anymore. I have tried lots and lots of the resources you mentioned and I can't get it to work, so your answer it's more than appreciated if you decide to put it back in.

Comment: here you go, in case you got an error please update the question with the new stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems, a) you're instantiating a `Fragment` programmatically but you're not attaching it to the `Activity`, so it's completly useless, and b) you're also instantiating a `Fragment` in the xml layout and that `Fragment` won't have a chance to have the arguments set before `onCreateView` is called. Therefore, if you need to remove the `Fragment` from the xml, create an instance in `Activity.onCreate`, set the arguments and then attach it to the `Activity` with `FragmentManager`

change `activity_main.xml` to this (note the `android:id` attribute)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.test.test.MainActivity">    

</FrameLayout>
```

and in `onCreate` of `MainActivity`

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("my_key", "My String");
MyFragment myFrag = new MyFragment();
myFrag.setArguments(bundle);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, myFrag, "myFrag")
    .commit();
```

Comment: please update the stacktrace of the error in the question

Answer (score 1):

you got error because you put the value in your 
bundle.putString("my_key", "My String");
and try to get the date from 
String getArgument = getArguments().getString("data");
please make sure which is your key my_key or data?

Comment: I corrected the code. It's exactly the same, I keep getting the error.

Comment: i again check your code and error report according to me the error is occur because of inflating layouts

Comment: @ragtime.sp please get your arguments and check the value exist in that with the help of Log.e("Value",""+getArguments().getString("my_key"));

Comment: The value exists. I don't know why I can't seem to get it working. Could you also change your answer as it keeps getting upvoted but the code is already corrected.

Comment: @ragtime.sp you got error because you put the value in your bundle.putString("my_key", "My String"); and try to get the date from Bundle bunlde=getArguments(); String getArgument = bundle.getString("my_key"); please make sure which is your key my_key or data?